# Keep domain while path forwarding on google domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

I have a google domain for danielokita.com. I currently have an IPFS file and am forwarding the file to the path of the IPFS file, this is the site here
https://danielokita.com. I want to make it so I can keep the domain name but still show the file example:

1. Go to danielokita.com
2. Show the IPFS file while while still showing the danielokita.com domain name.

For clarity, I am using path forwarding to display a file, I would like that it so that when I path forward I keep the google domain of danielokita.com instead of showing the IPFS link.

Edit: For those who don't know what an IPFS file is it is a file stored on a distributed file system called IPFS in which the file can be retrieved through an IPFS gateway and the hash of the file. You can see example of the file by clicking on the site. It is just a html file stored on a distributed server and I want to show the result of my page will hiding the hash on the domain name level.

Comment: What is **IPFS file** and how is that related to Google Cloud? Edit your question to clearly define your question and problem.

Comment: changed does this make more sense

Comment: No, your edit does not improve your question. 1) How is this related to Google Cloud? 2) What is your question/problem? Please read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I hope this make sense now, idk how to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my first thoughts, a masked redirect would solve the problem, sacrificing the SEO issue, but Google not only doesn't support masked redirect, but also ANAME/ALIAS.

So what I'm going to do is to use OVH and with masked redirection fix it. While I schedule on Amazon Amplify Hosting I will use Github or another IPFS provider like Fleek. This is how I plan to host all my websites for free and easy.

Comment: I am now using fleek + ENS, currently migrating my domains over to cloud fare as well thanks for the help!